# Ubuntu 18.04 restarts automaticaly daily more than twice?

Tags: 18.04, reboot, restart

**system configuration**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               45
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
```

My system reboots daily without my knowledge. Are there any solutions for this behaviour of my system. The output for `last reboot` is as follows:

```
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Fri May  8 11:26   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Fri May  8 08:24   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Thu May  7 16:32   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Thu May  7 08:31   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Wed May  6 17:18   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Wed May  6 16:41   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Wed May  6 08:35   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Wed May  6 08:26   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 23:28   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 17:51   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 16:45   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 09:59   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 08:28   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 08:13   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Tue May  5 07:34   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Mon May  4 10:44   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Mon May  4 09:48   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Mon May  4 07:53   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Mon May  4 03:26   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sun May  3 21:55   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sun May  3 09:16   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  2 17:06   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  2 13:34   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  2 08:35   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Fri May  1 07:20   still running

wtmp begins Fri May  1 07:20:08 2020
```

The output for the command `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
total 64
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jan 14 11:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug  6  2019 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug  6  2019 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 23 12:26 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

The ouput of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
`No such file or directory`

The output for the command `ps auxc | grep -i therm`

```
root       250  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May08   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
```

Comment: Is 5.3.0-51-generic correct for 18.04? We would need to see more of the log to get any idea what's wrong. The reboot times are pretty much similar... around 8am and 5pm. What's running at those times? Cron job?

Comment: It is not a cron job.  What are the logs files required?

Comment: Tell me if kernel 5.3.0-51 is normal for 18.04, or if you manually upgraded it. If the system rebooted today, post today's /var/log/syslog at paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: i did not do any manual upgradation. The iso downloaded from ubuntu website and was installed using pendrive. The system was working nicely for 4 months. This happened before two weeks

Comment: Let me know when you've posted syslog. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I pasted the syslog in the mentioned website [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2Ytk4HZ9sP/)

Comment: I've reviewed syslog. It's quite a mess. Please see my temporary answer. Edit your question with the details requested. Ping me when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing syslog, I found a lot of problems. We'll start with these...

**Software issues**

- FolderIconMenu is causing a problem

  - uninstall FolderIconMenu
- gnome-shell is crashing all over the place

  - go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/
  - turn off ALL extensions
  - delete these... `sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax*`
  - reinstall this... `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`
  - restart Gnome Shell... <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**Power Supply**

I was correct. The power supply has issues. Either it's under-rated for your configuration, or it's defective. The internal fan should also be verified. Running on a UPS should not cause the power supply to reboot the system, unless the UPS is having problems switching to backup.

Comment: I have updated the question with configuration and the commands mentioned in the answer

Comment: @svp Is this a desktop or server installation? Briefly describe your hardware configuration. What is that cron job?

Comment: @svp Please see/do my updated answer.

Comment: @svp Status please...

Comment: Hi performed the commands but still system restarts automatically. Can you help me to stop "Cron job"? @heynnema

Comment: @svp You've taken care of the obvious. That's good. That should quiet down syslog a big, and stop gnome-shell from crashing all the time. Is this a desktop computer? How old? Turns out the cron job is for sysstat, runs every 10 minutes, and is actually OK.

Comment: My system is Desktop Workstation with 10TB hard drive and 64 GB RAM. Installed version of ubuntu is 18.04 Desktop LTS version

Comment: @svp You may have a power supply problem. Is yours rated high enough? Power supply fan working properly? Side note... have you ever run memtest on this configuration? With 64G RAM, it'll take days to run...

Comment: I did not test any memtest on this configuration. Now I have removed installed tweak themes and set to default ubuntu theme. but still problem exists **reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sun May 10 11:18   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sun May 10 06:46   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  9 15:51   still running
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  9 15:36 - 15:48  (00:12)
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  9 08:22 - 15:48  (07:25)
reboot   system boot  5.3.0-51-generic Sat May  9 03:17 - 15:48  (12:31)**

Comment: @svp You didn't say how many watts your power supply is, or if it's internal fan is working. Let me see the current syslog. Also, lets bite the bullet and run memtest. If it hangs or crashes or reports errors or reboots, we'll know the next step.

Comment: @svp Exactly in which log are you seeing "5.3.0-51-generic Sun May 10 11:18 still running reboot system"? I'd like to see more of that log too.

Comment: @svp Status please...

Comment: Finally, I got the issue. The problem is with powersupply. There is power fluctuation when running on UPS. That small interval make the system to restart. It happens 3 to 4 times daily. @heynnema

Comment: @svp Good news! I was correct then, considering the power supply. I've updated my answer. If all of this was helpful, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your support.. cheers!!!